# Given all permutations of N-digits, what is the ratio of random-seeming vs non-random-seeming sequences?

Tags: permutations, random, compression

My question is inspired by the comment in [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/researchers-identify-master-problem-underlying-all-cryptography-20220406/) that the 20 digit sequence 03729563829603547134 seems "more random" than 99999999999999999999. One could use some measure of compressibility to quantify the "seeming randomness" of a given N-digit sequence: some threshold of compressibility could be set to distinguish "random-seeming" (RS) from "non-random-seeming" (NRS) sequences.

In such a situation, would there be a way to calculate the ratio of NRS sequences to RS sequences? Intuition suggests such a ratio would be small; but how small? To make it even more concrete, suppose we set the compressibility threshold at 80%. How can one calculate the ratio of >=80%-compressible 20-digit sequences to <80%-compressible 20-digit sequences? Does the ratio decrease with sequences of increasing length?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to get an answer would be to use the pigeonhole principle.

Let's assume we are working in base $b$, are looking at sequences of length $n$ and are considering a sequence to be 'well compressed' if it has length at most $m$.

Then we can see that the following is the number of sequence of length at most $m$, $K_m$

$$K_m=\sum_{i=0}^{m}b^i=\frac{b^{m+1}-1}{b-1}$$

Now note that there are $b^{n}$ sequences of length $n$.

As each 'non-random' sequence must be given a compressed form of length at most $m$, we see that the ratio of 'non-random' sequences to all sequences $r_{n,m}$ is at most

$$r_{n,m}=\frac{K_m}{b^n}=\frac{b^{m+1}-1}{b^{n+1}-b^n}$$

The ratio of 'non-random' to 'random' is then,

$$R_{n,m}=\frac{r_{n,m}}{1-r_{n,m}}=\frac{b^{m+1}-1}{b^{n+1}-b^n-b^{m+1}+1}$$

To get any better value than this would require you to choose a particular method of compression or add extra constraints.

The particular case you mention gives a ratio of at most $1.1111\times10^{-16}$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. I tried it on 20 digit sequences in base 10 with a compression to at most 19 digits (so only a compression of one digit was considered NRS, and even then the ratio is a mere 12.5%! With at most 18 digits, it goes down to 1.124%. With a 50% compression, ie at most 10 digits, the ratio is 1.1111 x 10^-10.

So it appears that the ratio of NRS/RS becomes vanishingly small quite quickly.

Comment: Yes it is true that the ratio gets very small very quickly. Not that it matters too much but technically if you are using percentages you want to use $r_{n,m}$ instead of $R_{n,m}$. It doesn't matter for high amouts of compression, but with very low compression it changes from $12.5$% to $11.11$%. Also it is worth metioning that in a certain sense this formula allows for 'too many' compressions and so arguably the numbers should be lower than they already are.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in looking into this more I would reccomend looking into shannon entropy and huffman encoding as this deals with how you can efficiently compress things when you know about how things are distributed. Of course that isn't striclty related to Kolmogorov complexity so it might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. I should have said that the Rm,n RATIO when m=19 and n=20 is 0.125. I shouldn't have mentioned percentages. Thanks again for your answer and suggestions!